# Do I need to do anything "special" to use the WebMatrix database helper in Visual Studio '12?

Tags: database, razor, visual-studio-2012, webmatrix-2

I'm doing some basic db querying in WebMatrix.

Something like,

```
@{
  var db = Database.Open("test"); //test is the name of my database
  var selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM MY_CUSTOM_TABLE"
}

//Doing a `@foreach` and showing the items from the table
```

When I do the same thing in Visual Studio,

I get an error `Connection String not found` at `var db = Database.Open("test");`.

Am I missing some `using` statements? or am I doing something utterly wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue was,

I hadn't defined a connection string in my web.config.

I did that and it gave me an `Instance Error`.

That took a while solving cause of weird escape sequence behavior. [This](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=89c01cae-e045-4b06-bff1-8dd2d596e266) helped me.